nvidia 560 drivers not available in Ubuntu 24.04
I running Ubuntu 24.04 and have a Nvidia RTX 4060 installed. One of the games I am trying to play on steam (via protonDB) seems like nvidia driver 560 would fix some performance issues according to some users.
However, I don't see the 560 driver available to use, only 550 and lower.
I think I saw an article somewhere saying that the 560 is still being tested and not officially supported yet? Is that accurate? And if so, is there a timeline anywhere with an ETA on when this will be made available (approximately)?

It is provided in Ubuntu 24.10. However, version 24.10 of Ubuntu is not as stable as version 24.04. So upgrading to 24.10 may make your experience worse.

Gotcha.. Yeah, I'd prefer to stay as stable as I can :). Are there any discussion boards that give updates on if/when it'll make it to 24.04?

If you add the graphics-drivers ppa you can install the NVIDIA 560 driver.  Or you can wait until it hits the Ubuntu repositories.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-560

or
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-560-open


Good to know! I did come across this a few weeks ago as well, but couldn't find it since lol.
Still though, do you know of any forums or life-cycle maps that'll give an idea/time frame when the 560 drivers will hit ubuntu's repos? Trying to avoid using the non-ubuntu repo for this just to stay stable in the long run :)

@Cloud9Developer I guess if they follow what it says in this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NVidiaUpdates that the driver release to the repos can take about 6-8 weeks after the release by NVIDIA.

@Cloud9Developer Ooops, I had the PPA on the wrong side of the graphics-drivers.  This is what I get when I am tired.  LOL!

Yep lol. I tried it out last night though, installed the 560, but had nothing but problems with it.. had to purge Nvidia completely and reinstall 550 (from Ubuntu) to fix everything :/

Ahh, I just found the driver information on Nvidia's website.. 560 isn't production ready yet, it's still in feature branch state

@Cloud9Developer I didn't look there, so that is good to know.  I did, however, install the 560 driver on my system here and it appears to be working just fine, but I will leave that as a note to maybe help you.  :)
